# SQL Azure - Could not able to alter column type

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

Today I created a new table in SQL Azure portal and by default there is an `Id INT` column.

`Id ( int , PK , Not Null)`

When I tried to change it to `BIGINT` it gave me the following error:

```
An error was encountered while applying the changes.An exception occurred
while executing the Transact-SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PerformanceData]
ALTER COLUMN [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL.
The object 'PrimaryKey_029c7a8d-e6b2-43b8-94f1-98fc5b0115e3' is dependent on
column 'Id'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Id failed because one or more objects
access this column.
```

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the column you are trying to alter is the primary key column. You need to drop related constraints first. Something like this:`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PerformanceData] DROP CONSTRAINT Id`