# Cannot drop/alter column in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

As the title says, I cannot drop or alter a column in SQL Azure. I wanted to change its datatype from int to tinyint. I did specify tinyint, but it seems Azure overrode that.
I've tried via the Management Console as well as from SSMS.
I found the following SO question, but importantly, my column is not a primary/foreign key and is not even used in an index.
[SQL Azure - Could not able to alter column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265992/sql-azure-could-not-able-to-alter-column-type)

In Aure Management Console, I get the following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>InternalError:7752a6bb-a244-f1a0-221b-b9c482ae6680</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">An error was encountered while applying the changes.&#xD;
An exception occurred while executing the Transact-SQL statement: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xxxxx] DROP COLUMN [EmailFrequency2].&#xD;
The object 'ColumnDefault_b0898c7d-0fb6-4466-8894-1325eb8c4efd' is dependent on column 'EmailFrequency2'.&#xD;
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN EmailFrequency2 failed because one or more objects access this column.</m:message></m:error>
```

I did try googling "InternalError:7752a6bb-a244-f1a0-221b-b9c482ae6680" but got zero hits.

I've tried disable constraints when attempting to alter the table (to change the datatype from int to tinyint):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xxxxx] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xxxxx] ALTER COLUMN [EmailFrequency] TINYINT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xxxxx] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

But I get basically the same error:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The object 'ColumnDefault_871cbb52-f294-4a57-9c51-b8fd435d0d59' is dependent on column 'EmailFrequency'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 2
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN EmailFrequency failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

I can't find any reference to the ColumnDefault_xxxx-GUID-xxx object anywhere

Can anyone suggest how I could get around this constraint? I was able to rename the table, but not drop it or change the datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value is a constraint you have in place, you have to delete it first:

```
ALTER TABLE xxxxx DROP CONSTRAINT <name of your default here>
```

Comment: ahaaaa! I updated my query to the above but got an error: "'ColumnDefault_871cbb52-f294-4a57-9c51-b8fd435d0d59' is not a constraint". 
HOWEVER, in the management console I removed the default value and was able to delete the column, so you definitely identified the core issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used code first migrations, and in my case, I was trying to make a property of a class not null by using `[Required]` annotation above the property. This kept giving me the JSON response "An error has occurred" when I tried to reach my endpoints.

After some time I realized I had records in that particular table, which had no value for the property I was trying to make not null, hence the error. Stupid mistake. I hope I can save someone from hours of googling. Haha.